# Control visibility of ArcGIS Server service by capability

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arccatalog, arcgis-10.3

I've got a service published on ArcGIS Server 10.3 that has feature access enabled along with the (always-enabled) MapServer. Is it possible to control the visibility of a service  such that the MapServer service doesn't show in ArcCatalog or ArcMap but the Feature Access service does? I see two services right now.

Tried disabling all available operations (Map, Query, Data) for the MapServer service to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. A map service will always have MapServer enabled because it is the core property. Feature Access and others (such as KML, Mobile, Network Analysis etc.) is just additional capabilities which you can enable when needed. So, there is no such service as "Feature Service" (even though this term became widely used); there is only "Map Service with Feature Acccess capability enabled".

Accessing the map service with the right URL in a web application (FeatureServer, not MapServer) and setting appropriate permissions to the service (ArcGIS Server permissions) when serving it to desktop clients will make your workflow efficient and you won't think that showing two services with the same name is a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Can you expound on setting the appropriate permissions? That may have been a better way of asking what I'm needing to do. Pretty sure you still mean we'll see two services in the desktop client, but thought I'd ask anyway

Comment: No problem. You set permissions per service - read more here. It won't affect what kind of capabilities your users will have access to though - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Configuring_ArcGIS_Server_security/0154000005qz000000/